# Pass promise to typeorm datasource conection options

Tags: typescript, typeorm, aws-ssm

Maybe this is a genral javascript question but i am strugling to find a way to get the datasource connection option from aws parameter store instead of storing them into enviroment variables, and maybe what i want to achieve is impossible but i want to get more expertise advises here.

This is my datasource class

```
let options = {
  type: "mssql" as any,
  host: AwsParameterStore.getParameter("DATABASE_HOST").then(
    async (secretKey) => {
      return secretKey;
    }
  ),
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  options: { encrypt: false },
  synchronize: false
};

export const VcsDatabase = new DataSource((options = options));
```

and this is my AwsParameterStore class

```
@Injectable()
export class AwsParameterStore {
  constructor(private eventLogger: LoggingService) {}
  static async getParameter(parameterName: string): Promise<any> {
    let ssm = new SSM({ region: "eu-west-1" });
    let options = {
      Name: parameterName
    };
    let parameter = ssm.getParameter(options).promise();
    return parameter.then((response) => {
      let token: string = response.Parameter.Value;
      return token;
    });
  }
}
```

Obviously this does not work because i am trying to pass the host value as promise when apparently typorm datasource only accept it as a string based on the error i am getting

```
connection error TypeError: The "config.server" property is required and must be of type string.
```

So i have 2 questions :

- Can we and if yes how to pass the connection parameters from another service (in my case from the AwsParameterStore)
- If this is not doable is it ok if i store the database credentials in the gitlab ci/cd variables and call it when runing the pipeline ?

I am more seeking to secure the credentials and as far as i know there in no other better way then storing those in ssm and retrieve it at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` the promise or put things into a `then` clause so it can finish before options gets passed in.  You can then export an `async` function which will need to be `await`ed where you use it.  It could look something like this

```
async function provideDataSource() {
    let options = {
        type: "mssql" as any,
        host: await AwsParameterStore.getParameter("DATABASE_HOST"),
        database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
        username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        options: { encrypt: false },
        synchronize: false
    };

    return new DataSource(options);  //  I don't think your code here was syntactically correct
}


export const provideVcsDatabase = provideDataSource;
```

and then you would import it and use it like

```
    const db = await provideVcsDatabase();
```

or

```
provideVcsDatabase().then(db => {
   // whatever
}
```